# Which data types are reference types by default?

Tags: c#

So while I was testing a method I made with a `DataRow` parameter, I sent in an argument and modified it inside the method. After that, my original `DataRow` changed to whatever it ended up being after the method. I realized this was because `DataRow` is a "reference type", which is new to me.

I now know that I can use "ref" or "out" before other data types when using methods so that the same effect as the `DataRow` example would happen. But my question is, which data types are reference types by default? I don't want to be caught off guard when I pass another kind of data type into a method and having the original value change.

Comment: For more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> But my question is, which data types are reference types by default?

Anything that is defined as a `class` is a reference type, as well as a variable referencing an `interface` or delegate, or a variable declared `dynamic`.  See [Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) for details.  You can change *members* of a class within a method without passing by `ref` or `out`.  That being said, you can't change the *reference itself* - so the variable will always point to the same instance after a method call as before the method call unless you pass it via `out` or `ref`.

If it's a `struct`, it will be a value type.

Comment: Interfaces and Delegates are also reference types:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx

Comment: @merthsoft Good point - Interfaces are a bit different - they can be used on a value type, but the interface variable itself is always a reference.  Int32 is a value type, even though it implements IComparable, but a variable can be a reference type referencing an Int32.

Comment: So right now, I have a method with parameters `DataRow`, `string`, and `bool`. I want to change all three and keep the changes in the originals. DataRow seems to be fine on its own, but the `string` and `bool` needed `ref` to work. Why is this, even though string is a `class`?

Comment: @Mindquake Because you're not changing member values in the string - you're assigning a new string.  That's why I mentioned that you can't "change the reference itself" without using `ref` - which is what's required to change a string in a method.

Comment: @Mindquake You can change values of members inside of the `DataRow` (since it's a class), but you can't change the `DataRow` itself without passing it by `ref`.

Comment: @Mindquake Personally, I like how Eric describes it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/07/references-and-pointers-part-one.aspx  "ref" should be thought of as "alias", which is distinct from reference type/value type

Comment: It's important to remember in this case that strings are immutable, and that's why it can be a little confusing when dealing with them in this kind of context. No matter what you do to the string, you're creating a new one--you're never changing member values directly. This was a concept that was a little unclear to me for a while.

Answer (score 1):

A better question is what types are not reference types.

[MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)

- Structs
- Enumerations

Structs fall into these categories:

- Numeric types: Integral types, Floating-point types and decimal
- bool
- User defined structs

Answer (score 0):

`ref` and `out` are *not* the same is the reference type. Infact the meaning of them depends on which type you use.

On `value type` `ref` keyword is a reference,

On `reference type` `ref` keyword is a reference to reference.

In `CLR` per default `classes` are `reference types`, ans `struct` is a `value type`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in c# is derived from `Object`..That's why you see a `toString()` and other methods even for int..

**-->Value Types**[occupies the required memory to store them]

{also called primitive types(except decimal) since they are directly supported by the processor}

> ->int,long,byte,flot,decimal...
>
> ->bool
>
> ->char

**-->Reference type**[requires seperate alloc of memory for the reference and the object]

```
->string

->object
```

**-->Generic Type Parameters**

> ->T(Example:TreeExample)

**-->Pointer types**

> ->marked as Unsafe code

**Parameters can be passed**

> ->by **value**(an exact copy is created in case of value type || only reference is copied incase of reference type)
>
> ->by **ref**(refers to the same object)
>
> ->by **out**(allows uninitialized data to be passed as parameter && is same as ref)

**Important fact**

**arguments in c# are `by default` passed by value**

Comment: This isn't entirely true - you can store a value type on the heap by boxing it.

Comment: yes you can..It also depends upon where you declare a value type..if a value type is declared as an instance field it is stored in 'heap'..